# How to set orientation for annotation text or value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I start learning using Google Visualization for my web.

I have some problem with annotation.  The annotation text is pile up, in my opinion the data is useless if its cannot read

[image: the annotation text is pile up, in my opinion the data is useless if its cannot read]

this is my code for the annotation

```
var options = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 680,
    vAxis: {title: 'QTY'},
    hAxis: {title: 'DAYS'},
    legend: { position: 'center', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '80%' },
    isStacked: true,
    title : 'PRODUCTION BY PROCESS <?php echo $proc;?> SECTION <?php echo $fact;?> <?php echo $Date ?> ',
    series: {20: {type: 'line'}}
};
```

How to set orientation for annotation text or value to counterclockwise or to make annotation text not pile up like the image.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP and not Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to rotate the annotations, change `style` to `'line'`

```
var options = {
  annotations: {
    style: 'line'
  }
};
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [
      "x",
      "y0",
      "y1",
      "y2",
      "y3"
    ],
    ["29-04-2017", 212558.50, 212558.2, 212558.4, 212555.5],
    ["13-05-2017", 212558.60, 212558.32, 212558.53, 212555.67],
    ["12-06-2017", 212558.30, 212558.72, 212558.13, 212555.37],
    ["23-08-2017", 212558.50, 212558.22, 212558.43, 212555.57]
  ]);

  var viewColumns = [0];
  $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1), function (index) {
    viewColumns.push(index + 1);
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, index + 1);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    });
  });
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      style: 'line'
    },
    colors: ["#0F5470", "#8EA3A4", "#3EB8BC", "#98D4F2"]
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works.

1 more question. Is there any of style for annotations beside the line style?

Comment: no other styles, but you can change the length of the stem and other settings, see the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

Comment: you could also [format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) the annotation numbers with a pattern of `'short'`, this would reduce `1,000,000` to `1M`